# Devise on rails 3 how can I trigger a custom code to run as soon as a user sign up?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have an action (`send_confcode`) that will send a confirmation code via sms as soon as a new user signs up. I would like to know where this action should be placed. Is it under the `User` model generated by Devise?

```
def send_confcode     
  @confcode = (Time.now.to_i).to_s.slice(6,9)
  # more code here for sending code via an sms api
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an `after_create` callback method in your User model. Add this to your user model:

```
after_create :send_confcode
```

After a user is created it will call the `send_confcode` method.

You can read more about Rails callbacks here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#callbacks-overview